# Java constant is different in different places

Tags: java, constants

So, we've pushed something to production, and it's working fine.  However, I see something in the logs that is highly unsettling.  Namely:

```
pr 0.1 -  wait time for fetchAndRemoveEntries: 0
pr 1.0 - f'n'r entries: uid: hbyk68jfhbf5th
```

Note that `pr` is different for the two lines.  Running a code search for `wait time for fetchAndRemoveEntries` returns only one result, as does `f'n'r entries`.  Both are `println`s.  The first is found in one of our API classes:

```
System.out.println("pr " + NotificationDataStorage.printReduction + " -  wait time for fetchAndRemoveEntries: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

The second is found in our class NotificationDataStorage, where printReduction is defined.  An abbreviated version of the class:

```
public class NotificationDataStorage {
  public static final double printReduction = 1;
  ...
  public static void addEntries(ArrayList<HashMap> data) {
    ... // No, I have did not declare 'printReduction' as a local variable.)
    System.out.println("pr " + printReduction + " - adding " + data.size() + " entries");
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Even ignoring the "addEntries" code, the fact that NotificationDataStorage.printReduction returns 0.1 when, in fact, it should be 1, is highly concerning.

We've actually been plagued with issues like this all week, though up until now they always disappeared when we pushed to a server.  We assumed they were local quirks, perhaps flaws of NetBeans.  I stepped through code in the debugger, looked at a constant as it was passed into a method A, and saw it change to a value from a previous build once I was in the scope of A.  The old value caused the code to crash.  I set it to log some things, and the problem mysteriously disappeared.  We've had code that inexplicably doesn't work, but after checking out a different branch and checking BACK into the branch that wasn't working, it suddenly starts working again.  Cleaning and building sometimes fixes it.  Sometimes not.

Part of the weird thing is, this is the first week that we've had these problems, as near as I can tell.  It's as if a week ago we wrote some code whose bits now summon a demon that messes with our constants.  Or, more accurately, it's as if when we update our constants, the change is only reflected in SOME of the places they're used.

The particular problem currently manifesting isn't problematic, but it's highly worrying that other constants might experience similar problems.

Does anybody have any insight or experience or explanations for this?

Comment: **"It's as if a week ago we wrote some code whose bits now summon a demon that messes with our constants. Or, more accurately, it's as if when we update our constants, the change is only reflected in SOME of the places they're used."** Are you recompiling all your code?  Or is it possible that there are some stale .class/.jar files laying around somewhere?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It's possible.  I don't know exactly how our build system works.  However, since the constants changed, everything else depending on those constants OUGHT to have been rebuilt as well, right?  Note that the problems seem to have occasionally survived cleaning and building (in NetBeans).  It's hard to tell, as the issues are erratic.

Comment: I would guess old jars/classes in the class path.

Comment: @Paul Note, however, that the constants we're using are (in the given case) a double, and in another case was a String.  Both are primitives - I don't think the linked answer is applicable for primitives.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well, at least that's a possible method of failure, though I'd still like to know WHY the old classes aren't getting rebuilt.

Comment: Java Specs say: *"If a primitive type or a string is defined as a constant and the value is known at compile time, the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value."* - And no, automatic detection of outdated constants is to my knowledge not a thing that compilers do (You didn't touch the .java? Assume .class is still good!) - in your case it'll even concatenate the strings with the numbers at compile time

Comment: @zapl Surely it does, though?  If you change a constant in code, the compiler ought to update all the places it's referenced.

Comment: @Erhannis the compiler doesn't necessarily know about those dependencies since the dependency is gone once the value was inlined. So the solution for many tools it to just recompile everything everytime. Related https://discuss.gradle.org/t/java-incremental-compilation/5138 . No idea how netbeans handles recompilation, maybe some flawed incremental hotswapping only some parts?. Constants are a known to pose problems especially once you use them across .jar files where you typically don't recompile code just because a dependency changed.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly due to not all the code getting recompiled.

your field is `public static final double` which will get the value inlined at compile time.  This is a huge problem if the value ever changes because old classes that aren't recompiled will not have their value updated!  If the code that references this field is in a different jar it probably won't get recompiled either.

[The Java Security Coding Guidelines DCL59-J](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/DCL59-J.+Do+not+apply+public+final+to+constants+whose+value+might+change+in+later+releases) covers this problem

> The final keyword can be used to specify constant values (that is, values that cannot change during program execution). However, constants that can change over the lifetime of a program should not be declared public final. The Java Language Specification (JLS) [JLS 2013] allows implementations to insert the value of any public final field inline in any compilation unit that reads the field. Consequently, if the declaring class is edited so that the new version gives a different value for the field, compilation units that read the public final field could still see the old value until they are recompiled. This problem may occur, for example, when a third-party library is updated to the latest version but the referencing code is not recompiled.

The solution is to make the field `private` and use a public static getter method instead.

```
 private static final double PRINT_REDUCTION = 1; //will change often

 public static double getPrintReduction(){
        return PRINT_REDUCTION;
 }
```

Notice I also capitalized the field which is a java coding convention for constants.

This topic and many more issues are covered in [Java Coding Guidelines Recommendations Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EQ8D31A)

Comment: I should mention that the constant and both references to it are a part of the same project, and get compiled into the same jar file. The text you reference seems to be discussing references between jar files, though it's a bit unclear. Consider: `compilation units that read the public final field could still see the old value until they are recompiled`. Since both classes are part of the same project, cleaning and building should update them both. We have an entire class "constants.java". This is a standard practice, yes? Updating constants there USUALLY takes effect throughout the project.

Comment: you mentioned this problems happens sometimes in production.  Is it possible that there are old versions of the classes in the classpath too?  It might also be worth changing your `Constants.java` class to use the solution I explained to see if the problem still persists

Comment: It's possible that it would fix it.  If the problem persists or becomes worse, I may include that solution in a more rigorous attempt to ferret it out.  However, that aside, I'd like to verify that we're both on the same page, namely: the behavior I'm describing, occurring by the process you describe, is erroneous.  Given two classes in a single project, if you change a constant in A and it's referenced in B, compiling the project should compile not only A but also B.  Correct?  That's part of the job of the compiler: recompiling classes according to dependencies.

Comment: that is correct assuming the newly compiled class is getting loaded by the classloader on your production server and not an old out of date one.  I've had that problem before where multiple versions of the jar are on the classpath and a mix and match of classes was loaded from each jar

Comment: Hmm, weird.  Ok; thanks.  Maybe I'll check if there are old copies of the jar, or something....